# Handling CSS errors in Javafx

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am writing a JavaFX program, where the user enters a color's Hex value and its set as a background color of StakePane. The code is:

`stakePane.styleProperty().setValue("-fx-background-color: "+inputValue+";");`

It works fine for a valid Hex value input.But when the user enters invalid Hex value its gives the following error on console:

> javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue
>
> WARNING: Could not resolve '#E91E63g' while resolving lookups for '-fx-background-color' from inline style on ComboBox@20f56ee2[styleClass=combo-box-base combo-box]

I tried `try catch` to handle this error. But the error is not caught.

[JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introparserwarnings) says:

> "Applications needing to detect errors from the parser can add a listener to the errors property of com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager."

How can I handle CSS errors in javafx?

Comment: Could you share your try-catch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real java exception thrown on such an error. Instead only a warning is printed by the global `StyleManager` that is responsible for applying the CSS to the Scene.
But happily the `StyleManager` holds an observable list containing all errors that occurred. As stated by the reference guide you can simply add a listener to it. You get notified and you can handle errors accordingly.

```
com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.errorsProperty().addListener((ListChangeListener<? super CssError>) c -> {
        while(c.next()) {
            for(CssError error : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                // maybe you want to check for specific errors here
                System.out.println(error.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

But I think in your case it would be better to check the input string for a valid format before applying it to the CSS ;)

Answer (score -1):

You could simply validate the color before applying it to a stackpane. If the color is not a valid color then set a default color.

Below is a simple example that applies hex color values to a stackpane. The colorValues are stored in a comboBox. Now before setting the background color to stackpane, I call a method **getColorValue(String colorValue)**. Now, if the color is a valid color then i set the color otherwise i print a message and set a default color. The default color in the below example is a Red color(#F00000).

To validate the color, i am using a regex.

```
  private static final String HEX_PATTERN = "^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$";
```

The regex is simple. It looks for a 6 letter value denoted by **[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}** or a 3 letter value denoted by [A-Fa-f0-9]{3}. The color value must start with a '#' sign.

```
 public class ColorApp extends Application {


    String backGroundColor = "";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Label messageLabel = new Label("Color NOT SELECTED FROM COMBOBOX");

        ObservableList<String> options =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        "DEFG",
                        "#ZZZAAA",
                        "#ABCDEF",
                        "#055"
                );

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();

        final ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox(options);
        comboBox.setItems(options);
        stackPane.getChildren().addAll(messageLabel,comboBox);
        StackPane.setAlignment(messageLabel,Pos.TOP_LEFT);

        comboBox.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                backGroundColor = newValue;
                stackPane.styleProperty().setValue("-fx-background-color: " + (backGroundColor = ColorUtils.getColorValue(backGroundColor)) + ";");
                messageLabel.setText(backGroundColor + " Applied");

            }
        });


        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane,600,800);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}

class ColorUtils {

    private static final String HEX_PATTERN = "^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$";
    static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(HEX_PATTERN);
    static Matcher matcher;
    private static final String DEFAULT_COLOR_VALUE = "#F00000";

    public static String getColorValue(String colorValue) {
        matcher = pattern.matcher(colorValue);
        boolean result = matcher.matches();
        if (result == false) {
            System.out.println("Invalid colorValue detected, colorValue==" + colorValue);
            System.out.println("Setting default Color Value to RED");
            return DEFAULT_COLOR_VALUE;
        } else {
            return colorValue;
        }
    }
}
```

If the color that was selected from comboBox got validated, the following output will be shown.
Color Validated:
[image]

Color Not Validated:
[image]

Edit: Note that i am using a stackpane and manually setting a position to a label. This is not recommended.It is for demonstration purpose only.